# Call another Rest API from my Rest API through ActiveMQ

Tags: rest, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Can I call another Rest API from my API through ActiveMQ using Spring Boot? I read this [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/rest), and I see examples but they are calling from same API, but I wanted to call another API URL through ActiveMQ.

I have one Spring Boot application (B) exposed via REST on one server and I have another Spring Boot application (REST Client)(A) in another server.

A is an automated Java application that listen on some port and when data comes it makes request and then POST it to B application exposed via REST. However, now I want to add ActiveMQ in middle like this:

```
A --> ActiveMQ--> B
```

ActiveMQ will be always be the middle-man between A and B, but I have to make application architecture like if App B is down data will be stored in ActiveMQ from App A and if both application is running the A send data to ActiveMQ and B dequeue that data.

How can I achieve that?

I saw a lot a example online but they are doing this by passing `[@PostMapping]` and `[@GetMapping]` within REST API, but that doesn't fulfill my purpose.

Comment: Yes, you are right I have one Spring boot application(B) exposed via REST on another server and I have another Spring Boot application(REST Client)(A) in another server that will generate a request and send it to B, but now which URL I have to pass because I want to store my data in ActiveMQ, so If the B application is down it will still store the Data and when B application up again it will deque that same Data.

Comment: ok, I will tell you what I have to do, A is an automated Java application that listen on some port and when data comes it makes request and then POST it to B application exposed via REST, but now I want to add ActiveMQ in middle like this A --> ActiveMQ--> B, So if B is down, A stores data in ActiveMQ and when B up again it will deque the data, how can I achieve that, I saw a lot a example online but they are doing this by passing [@PostMapping] and [@GetMapping] within REST api, but that doesn't fulfill my purpose.

Comment: ActiveMQ will be always middle man between A and B, but I have to make application architecture like if App B is down Data will store in ActiveMQ from App A and if both applicatino is running the A send data to ActiveMQ and B dequeue that Data.

Answer (score 0):

Your program that calls (REST Client) A can be updated to send data to ActiveMQ using any number of protocols-- JMS, REST, STOMP, etc. Since you are using Spring, you may want to consider the JMSTemplate, or use ActiveMQ's REST endpoint to send to a Queue (ie queue://APPB.INPUT).

The consumer side will need an additional component that is either standalone, or part of the Spring Boot Application B. Perhaps a Spring JMS Listener or Camel route that reads from the Queue (ie queue://APPB.INPUT) and then sends the data to the application B REST endpoint.

Current design:

```
App A (REST Client) -> App B (REST Service)
```

Event Driven / Asynchronous design:

```
App A (JMS Producer Client) -> ActiveMQ -> App B (JMS Consumer Client) -> App B (REST Service)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, I get what you are saying, but let's suppose if I add JMS Consumer Client in App B then if I have to stop the App B and App A is still running then will ActiveMQ will store data from App A?

Comment: Yes, that is a primary use case for ActiveMQ. ActiveMQ stores the data from A while B is down for planned or unplanned outages. The Producer and Consumer do _not_ need to be running at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, Let me implement the solution and I'll get back to you.